# Win8.1 Drivers for ASUS Prime A520M-K MB Ryzen proc

Tags: windows-8.1, amd-processor

I don’t know how to install drivers for that processor with graphics, only Win 10 and 11 are available but I will never install them, I want any solution for Windows 8.1 which allows me to install drivers properly work, can anybody give advice, please

I have already tried different versions of the driver from AMD older versions and installed it in different ways through the device manager, but it simply does not install,-- writes the Basic Microsoft adapter